# Does "Mira" mean anything as a Japanese name?

Tags: names

English Wikipedia on [Mira (given name)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mira_(given_name)) says it's a Japanese name, but no real-life Japanese person with known written format for their name in Japanese is shown.

All Japanese examples are fictional and in kana, no kanji.

So is "Mira" a name used by real Japanese people? If so, do they also only use kana? Or is there at least one person that uses kanji? If the latter, what's their name mean?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that a name need not have associated kanji to be a valid Japanese name. Here's a famous person named ミラ though. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%89%E5%AF%BF%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9

Comment: ^ 安寿ミラ の本名は、 馬場貴子 ですけどね..

Comment: @Chocolate Thank you for pointing that out, though whether that matters to the OP is presumably something they would need to explain. They seemed open to the idea that if a Japanese person were listed in the English list that would have satisfied their question, but maybe they can expand on that. It's also possible to find plenty of suggestions for kanji that would fit the reading みら on name sites, though that doesn't necessarily mean real people have used them before.

Comment: @Leebo - Yeah, you're right. I'm looking for names at least one person used, with kanji to impart meaning. If no one uses it, then it's only a hypothetical name.

Comment: One of my friends has a very European-sounding name. And it's their 本名, which can totally pass as a European name. I have always thought their name was written in kana only. But I recently learned of their name's kanji... Let's just say it's a very uncommon kanji combination that I have never seen in names.

Answer (score 2):

ミラ is not a common traditional Japanese name. There is no typical kanji associated with this name (although [it's easy](https://b-name.jp/%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/f/yomi/%E3%81%BF%E3%82%89/289191) to assign kanji that can be read as みら). You may find ミラ in stage names and fictional characters' names, but they are typically written in katakana, and I believe most of them are ones inspired by foreign names. ありす happens to be part of a traditional Japanese surname (see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13901/5010)), but I'm not aware of such an interesting coincidence regarding ミラ.